# Best Intel Quick Sync software for h.264 transcoding

Tags: video, software-rec, h.264, hardware-acceleration, video-encoding

I would like to know the best (fast) software for video encoding and transcoding video into h.264 that makes use of [Intel Quick Sync](http://www.intel.com/technology/quicksync/index.htm).

I looked at Media Espresso by Cyberlink but it does not have many features. I can't even put a logo on the video using this. Just that one feature would really help.

But nothing else even comes close to the speed of encoding with my i7 2600k.

Comment: I have the same processor, but the last line of your question adds *absolutely no value or merit* whatsoever.  **Do you mean no other software comes close to the speed that Media Espresso does?** Or are you just assuming that it will be slower without Intel Quick Sync?

Comment: @Breakthrough For what it's worth, I didn't understand it as well.

Comment: I'm guessing Prakash means the speed with Quick Sync - benchmarks I've seen show it an order of magnitude faster than transcoding on a dedicated enthusiast GPU!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant the speed of other software which do not use quick sync but have additional features. I also tried cyberlinks power director which allows me to add logos and also has quick sync support but i'm just looking for an encoding application

Answer (score 3):

I hope I interpreted your question correctly. From [Intel's Quick Sync page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/quick-sync-video/quick-sync-video-general.html):

> Many independent software vendors (ISVs) have begun optimizing their
>   products for this new technology, including:
>
> - [Arcsoft MediaConverter](http://www.arcsoft.com/intouch/intelsnbconsumer)
> - [Arcsoft MediaImpression](http://www.arcsoft.com/intouch/intelsnbconsumer)
> - [Badaboom Media Converter](http://badaboomit.com/node/562)
> - [Corel Digital Studio](http://www.corel.com/corel/product/index.jsp?pid=prod3430188&cid=catalog50008&segid=979&storeKey=ca&languageCode=en)
> - <s>[CyberLink MediaEspresso](http://www.cyberlink.com/stat/events/OptimizeforIntel/index.jsp)</s> (you've tried that)
> - [CyberLink PowerDirector](http://www.cyberlink.com/stat/events/OptimizeforIntel/index.jsp)
> - [MainConcept](http://www.mainconcept.com/intel_qsv)
> - [Movavi Video Converter](http://www.movavi.com/intel.html)
> - [Roxio Creator](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/creator/suite/)

Still, if you consider adding a logo as a necessary feature, you're probably gonna have a hard time finding software.

Answer (score 1):

I always use **FFMpeg** for that.

*Decode*

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mp4
```

*Encode*

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 25 output.mp4
```

*Encode & Decode*

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 25 output.mp4
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync

Answer (score 0):

"Currently Intel’s Quick Sync transcode is only supported by two applications: Cyberlink’s Media Espresso 6 and Arcsoft’s Media Converter 7." [annadtech]
and both are not advanced in their options.

actually this data is not updated. many more are availble. http://www.intel.com/technology/quicksync/index.htm but they do not support logo overlays.

you should demo ArcSoft MediaImpression® 3 , its a video editor of some sort so mybe...